# Push a phone call to Flash Media Server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http-live-streaming, flash-media-server, pbx

I'm trying to figure out the first steps of this project. I have used AMS and Flash Builder. But how do we get a user to pick up a phone and dial into AMS and have that streamed?

Asterisk? 
Some other kind of PBX solution?

Answer (score 1):

In order to push a phone call to Flash media server you should leverage the capabilities of Flash media gateway. FMG is a RTMP based SIP server implementation. So you receive a call from regular phone lines and forward it to any of your SIP server implementations and map that SIP server to your FMG so that you can redirect the calls coming on your SIP account to FMG and through that to FMS. An open implementation to FMG include SIP-RTMP [ http://code.google.com/p/siprtmp/ ]

Some references on FMG: 
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/766836
hope this will help you.